# Make an order of products without login

Tags: login

I am trying to create an eshop/site in Wordpress CMS in which I can add products to cart without having to login/register and when I procceed to checkout only an email will notify about the order. Is there any plugin or another to achieve something like that.

In short I want someone to check the products he/she wants and then add them to a cart and only a email will notify me about the order.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would think any of the WordPress commerce plugins would support this fine, e.g. I'm fairly sure WooCommerce supports guest checkout.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean "only an email will notify about the order" ? That no record of the order is left in the database?

Comment: Exactly. The order will be on the fly, no order records or customer records.